# Linear independence of Indicators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, independence

Let $x_1<\dots<x_n$, then are the functions
$$
1_{[0,x_i]},
$$
linearly independent in $L^1$?

It seems obvious to me but I can't show it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\sum c_iI_{[0,x_i]}=0$. Then  $\sum c_iI_{[0,x_i]}(x)=0$ for almost all $x$. Take $x \in (x_{n-1},x_n)$ for which the equation holds to get $c_n=0$. Then take $x \in (x_{n-2},x_{n-1})$  and so on.